# How to change a float64 number to uint64 in a right way?

Tags: go, floating-point, type-conversion, floating-point-conversion

```
package main

func main() {
    var n float64 = 6161047830682206209
    println(uint64(n))
}
```

The output will be:

```
6161047830682206208
```

It looks like that when `float64` change to `uint64`, the fraction is discarded.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The problem here is the representation of constants and floating point numbers.

Constants are represented in arbitrary precision. Floating point numbers are represented using the [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) standard.

[Spec: Constants:](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Constants)

> Numeric constants represent values of arbitrary precision and do not overflow.

[Spec: Numeric types:](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Numeric_types)

> ```
> float64     the set of all IEEE-754 64-bit floating-point numbers
> ```

In IEEE 754 the double precision which is using 64 bits (`float64` in Go) **53 bits** are used to store the digits. This means the max digits (max number) that can be represented is the number of digits of `2<<52` which is (1 bit is for sign):

```
2<<52        : 9007199254740992
Your constant: 6161047830682206209
```

15.95 digits to be precise (16 digits, but not all values that you can describe with 16 digits, only up to `9007199254740992`).

The integer constant you try to put into a variable of type `float64` simply **does not fit**  into 52 bits so it has to be rounded and digits (or bits) will be cut off (lost).

You can verify this by printing the original `n float64` number:

```
var n float64 = 6161047830682206209
fmt.Printf("%f\n", n)
fmt.Printf("%d\n", uint64(n))
```

Output:

```
6161047830682206208.000000
6161047830682206208
```

The problem is not with conversion, the problem is that the `float64` value you try to convert is already not equal to the constant you tried to assign to it.

**Just for curiosity:**

Try the same with a much bigger number: +500 compared to the first const:

```
n = 6161047830682206709 // +500 compared to first!
fmt.Printf("%f\n", n2)
fmt.Printf("%d\n", uint64(n2))
```

Output **still** the same (the last digits / bits are cut off, +500 included!):

```
6161047830682206208.000000
6161047830682206208
```

Try a smaller number whose digits can be represented precisely using 52 bits (less than ~16 digits):

```
n = 7830682206209
fmt.Printf("%f\n", n)
fmt.Printf("%d\n", uint64(n))
```

Output:

```
7830682206209.000000
7830682206209
```

Try it on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/JERFLKyN-B).

Answer (score 7):

The problem is not with the conversion but that the number is too large an integer to be stored *exactly* as a `float64`. The assignment to `n` results in some loss of significance.

If you think about it, your number (about 6e18) is very close to the largest `uint64` (2^64-1 or about 18e18).  A `uint64` uses all of it's 64 bits to store an integer but a `float64` must use some of its 64 bits to store an exponent so it's going to have less bits to remember the mantissa.

In summary, if you assign a `uint64` (or integer constant) larger than about 10^15 to a `float64` and back to a `uint64` you will get a close, but probably not exactly the same, value.

[BTW Icza's answer is good and correct. I hope this answer is simple summary.]