# Does Go compiler's evaluation differ for constant expression and other expression

Tags: go, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bit-shift, evaluation

Why does below code fail to compile?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "unsafe"
)

var x int = 1

const (
    ONE     int = 1
    MIN_INT int = ONE << (unsafe.Sizeof(x)*8 - 1)
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(MIN_INT)

}
```

I get an error

> main.go:12: constant 2147483648 overflows int

Above statement is correct. Yes, 2147483648 overflows int (In 32 bit architecture). But the shift operation should result in a negative value ie -2147483648.

But the same code works, If I change the constants into variables and I get the expected output.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "unsafe"
)

var x int = 1

var (
    ONE     int = 1
    MIN_INT int = ONE << (unsafe.Sizeof(x)*8 - 1)
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(MIN_INT)

}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is a difference in evaluation between constant and non-constant expression that arises from constants being precise:

> Numeric constants represent exact values of arbitrary precision **and do not overflow**.

Typed constant expressions cannot overflow; if the result cannot be represented by its type, it's a compile-time error (this can be detected at compile-time).

The same thing does not apply to non-constant expressions, as this can't be detected at compile-time (it could only be detected at runtime). Operations on variables can overflow.

**In your first example** `ONE` is a typed constant with type `int`. This constant expression:

```
ONE << (unsafe.Sizeof(x)*8 - 1)
```

Is a constant [shift expression](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Operators), the following applies: [Spec: Constant expressions:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Constant_expressions)

> If the left operand of a constant [shift expression](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Operators) is an untyped constant, the result is an integer constant; **otherwise it is a constant of the same type as the left operand, which must be of [integer type](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Numeric_types)**.

So the result of the shift expression must fit into an `int` because this is a constant expression; but since it doesn't, it's a compile-time error.

**In your second example** `ONE` is not a constant, it's a variable of type `int`. So the shift expression here may –and will– overflow, resulting in the expected negative value.

**Notes:**

Should you change `ONE` in the 2nd example to a constant instead of a variable, you'd get the same error (as the expression in the initializer would be a constant expression). Should you change `ONE` to a variable in the first example, it wouldn't work as variables cannot be used in constant expressions (it must be a constant expression because it initializes a constant).

### Constant expressions to find min-max values

You may use the following solution which yields the max and min values of `uint` and `int` types:

```
const (
    MaxUint = ^uint(0)
    MinUint = 0
    MaxInt  = int(MaxUint >> 1)
    MinInt  = -MaxInt - 1
)

func main() {
    fmt.Printf("uint: %d..%d\n", MinUint, MaxUint)
    fmt.Printf("int: %d..%d\n", MinInt, MaxInt)
}
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/zxduLFqdM_)):

```
uint: 0..4294967295
int: -2147483648..2147483647
```

The logic behind it lies in the [Spec: Constant expressions:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Constant_expressions)

> The mask used by the unary bitwise complement operator ^ matches the rule for non-constants: the mask is all 1s for unsigned constants and -1 for signed and untyped constants.

So the typed constant expression `^uint(0)` is of type `uint` and is the max value of `uint`: it has all its bits set to `1`. Given that integers are represented using [2's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement): shifting this to the left by `1` you'll get the value of max `int`, from which the min `int` value is `-MaxInt - 1` (`-1` due to the `0` value).

### Reasoning for the different behavior

Why is there no [overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_overflow) for constant expressions and overflow for non-constant expressions?

The latter is easy: in most other (programming) languages there is overflow. So this behavior is consistent with other languages and it has its benefits.

The real question is the first: why isn't overflow allowed for constant expressions?

Constants in Go are more than values of typed variables: they represent *exact values of arbitrary precision*. Staying at the word *exact*, if you have a value that you want to assign to a *typed* constant, allowing overflow and assigning a completely different value doesn't really live up to *exact*.

Going forward, this type checking and disallowing overflow can catch mistakes like this one:

```
type Char byte
var c1 Char = 'a' // OK
var c2 Char = '世' // Compile-time error: constant 19990 overflows Char
```

What happens here? `c1 Char = 'a'` works because `'a'` is a `rune` constant, and `rune` is alias for `int32`, and `'a'` has numeric value `97` which fits into `byte`'s valid range (which is `0..255`).

But `c2 Char = '世'` results in a compile-time error because the rune `'世'` has numeric value `19990` which doesn't fit into a `byte`. If overflow would be allowed, your code would compile and assign `22` numeric value (`'\x16'`) to `c2` but obviously this wasn't your intent. By disallowing overflow this mistake is easily caught, and at compile-time.

To verify the results:

```
var c1 Char = 'a'
fmt.Printf("%d %q %c\n", c1, c1, c1)

// var c2 Char = '世' // Compile-time error: constant 19990 overflows Char
r := '世'
var c2 Char = Char(r)
fmt.Printf("%d %q %c\n", c2, c2, c2)
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/IcufRCuzFk)):

```
97 'a' a
22 '\x16'
```

To read more about constants and their philosophy, read the blog post: [The Go Blog: Constants](https://blog.golang.org/constants)

And a couple more questions (+answers) that relate and / or are interesting:
[Golang: on-purpose int overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34704843/golang-on-purpose-int-overflow)
[How does Go perform arithmetic on constants?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38982278/how-does-go-perform-arithmetic-on-constants)
[Find address of constant in go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35146286/find-address-of-constant-in-go)
[Why do these two float64s have different values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27819137/why-do-these-two-float64s-have-different-values)
[How to change a float64 number to uint64 in a right way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30897208/how-to-change-a-float64-number-to-uint64-in-a-right-way)
[Writing powers of 10 as constants compactly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34124294/writing-powers-of-10-as-constants-compactly)

Comment: As a follow up for the question, Can I use the second form to find the Minimum int value? Or Is there a better way to get the minimum int value?

Comment: Just curious to know. Why do we need two different behavior? Is there a specific reason for allowing overflown value for variables but not for constants?

Comment: @spartan: compared to some other languages I see an advantage in this behaviour as it is always clear and you wont get strange results from some (internal) conversions you dont understand. Such problems are usually difficult to resolve and debug. I like the type system in Go and the way it deals with conversions. In case I get an overflow at compile time for fmt.Println(math.MaxUint64), where math.MaxUint64 is an untyped constant value, I simply convert it into a typed value by surrounding it with its type, in this case fmt.Println(uint64(math.MaxUint64)).