# overflow bug with uint64 type, if overflow happens in function

Tags: go

Why the following code works without overflow bug?:
(overflow bug with uint64 type, if overflow happens in function)

```
package main


func foo(i uint64) int{

    return (1 << i)
}

func main() {

    foo(99)

}
```

A simple `bar := 1 << 99` would cause a bug. if you put `bar := 1 << 99` you get `prog.go:11:9: constant 633825300114114700748351602688 overflows int`.

And `bar := 1 << 512` gives `prog.go:11:11: shift count too large: 512`

https://play.golang.org/p/0iiUlCiYTDR

Comment: The go [spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Integer_operators) says `There is no upper limit on the shift count` -- why do you expect an error?

Comment: Another relevant quote from the spec: `For signed integers, the operations +, -, *, /, and << may legally overflow and the resulting value exists and is deterministically defined by the signed integer representation, the operation, and its operands.`

Comment: we have unsigned integers here

Comment: And what exactly is meant here by "overflow bug"?

Comment: if you put `bar := 1 << 99` you get `prog.go:11:9: constant 633825300114114700748351602688 overflows int`

Comment: and `bar := 1 << 512` gives `prog.go:11:11: shift count too large: 512`

Comment: @dibbidabbi For that see [Does go compiler's evaluation differ for constant expression and other expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39444852/does-go-compilers-evaluation-differ-for-constant-expression-and-other-expressio/39445372#39445372).

Comment: Inside the fonction it’s unsigned, but on your simple bar :=  1 << 99 example, it’s not.

Answer (score 1):

According to the ["Integer Operations" section of the language spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Integer_operators):

> There is no upper limit on the shift count.

So the behavior you see is intended.

Note that if you are using constants for both of the operands then the compiler will try to replace the statement with a constant, which *may* overflow your defined type:

```
x := uint64(1) << 500
// ERROR: constant ... overflows uint64
```

However, you can shift any integer by any value, any number of times:

```
x, y := uint64(1), uint64(0xffffffff)
for {
  x <<= y
}
// OK: x definitely has no bits set
```

Comment: there is an upper limit of 511

Comment: @dibbidabbi if you're using a constant shift value then the compiler will attempt to replace the statement with a constant, whose resulting value _may_ overflow the type you've defined. However, you can still shift any number of times, with any value in `[0,maxUint64]`.

Comment: sounds better, thanks. the compiler should be more consistent.