# time.Duration * time.Duration applied twice

Tags: go

Assuming I have:

```
t := 10 * time.Second // 10s,
```

what's going on behind the scene when time.Second is applied again?

```
tt := t * time.Second // -2346317h47m53.709551616s
```

https://play.golang.org/p/upyjGgsuVQm

Comment: `time.Second` is `1000000000`, what did you expect to happen? (or are you just asking about rollover to a negative value?)

Comment: the rollover to the negative value;
initializing 10 * time.Second * time.Second throws an error, but I'm curious why it doesn't in the original post

Comment: Don't multiply something that's already a `time.Duration` by one of the `Duration` constants; doing so doesn't make any sense. It's not clear what the intent of doing that would even be.

Comment: `10 * time.Second * time.Second` is a constant expression.  See the [specification for how constant expressions are evaluated](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Constant_expressions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [`time.Duration`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Duration) value is a numeric value that represents number of *nanoseconds*.

> A Duration represents the elapsed time between two instants as an int64 nanosecond count. The representation limits the largest representable duration to approximately 290 years.

> ```
> type Duration int64
> ```

Whatever arithmetic you perform on `time.Duration` values, they are performed numerically just as on `int64` values.

[`time.Second`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Second) is a (typed) constant holding the number of nanoseconds in one second, so multiplying it by `10` will give you the number of nanoseconds in 10 seconds. This fits "perfectly" into an `int64` number. As the documentation states, `int64` may store number of nanoseconds up to about 290 years.

Now if `t` holds number of nanonseconds in 10 seconds, and you multiply that by the number of nanoseconds in 1 second, using 64-bit integers, that will overflow:

```
fmt.Println(math.MaxInt64)
fmt.Print(int64(10*time.Second), "*", int64(time.Second))
```

Outputs:

```
9223372036854775807
10000000000*1000000000
```

Note that `t` is a variable, and so overflow is OK. Constants in Go are exact values and do not overflow. So `10 * time.Second * time.Second` would be a constant value that does not fit into `int64` and hence it gives an error when you try to assign the result to a variable that's backed by an `int64`. For details see [Does Go compiler's evaluation differ for constant expression and other expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39444852/does-go-compilers-evaluation-differ-for-constant-expression-and-other-expressio/39445372#39445372)