# math/big: constant 18446744073709551616 overflows int?

Tags: go, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bit-shift

I found some [odd looking code in the math/big library](https://golang.org/src/math/big/arith.go) and don't understand how it works. I have extracted the constants out into an example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/bits"
)

const (
    _S = _W / 8 // word size in bytes

    _W = bits.UintSize // word size in bits
    _B = 1 << _W       // digit base
    _M = _B - 1        // digit mask
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(_S, _W, _B, _M)
}
```

Returns the error:

```
bug/example.go:17:13: constant 18446744073709551616 overflows int
bug/example.go:17:13: constant 18446744073709551615 overflows int
```

To be clear, I understand why this code doesn't work. What I'm interested in is knowing is why this error *doesn't* happen when this constant is used in the standard library?

I thought it might be late evaluated (ie `_B - 1`) but I can see it's [literally used in tests](https://golang.org/src/math/big/nat_test.go#L26). So what value would be used here?

Answer (score 0):

*"constant 18446744073709551616 overflows int?"* -- Yes.

[`int`](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#int) depending on the architecture is at least 32 bits. [`int32`](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#int32) max value is `2147483647` and [`int64`](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#int64) max value is `9223372036854775807` both of which are not large enough to hold `18446744073709551615`.

---

https://golang.org/ref/spec#Constants

> Numeric constants represent exact values of arbitrary precision and do
> not overflow. Consequently, there are no constants denoting the
> IEEE-754 negative zero, infinity, and not-a-number values.

> A constant may be given a type explicitly by a constant declaration or
> conversion, or implicitly when used in a variable declaration or an
> assignment or as an operand in an expression. **It is an error if the
> constant value cannot be represented as a value of the respective
> type.**

In your case, based on the expression in which it is used, the constant value is given the type `int`, and since it cannot be represented by that type it results in an error.

---

You could convert the constants to `float64` (or `uint` in the case of `_M`) if you want the code to compile.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/bits"
)

const (
    _S = _W / 8 // word size in bytes

    _W = bits.UintSize // word size in bits
    _B = 1 << _W       // digit base
    _M = _B - 1        // digit mask
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(_S, _W, float64(_B), uint(_M))
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/AVT5FPHinT3

---

For more see: [Does Go compiler's evaluation differ for constant expression and other expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39444852/does-go-compilers-evaluation-differ-for-constant-expression-and-other-expressio)

Comment: Thanks, I understand why it doesn't work. What I'm interested in is how that code in the standard library doesn't error in the same way?

Comment: @ElliotChance `math/big` doesn't call `Printf` with it. It does use it to initialize a `uint`, but the value isn't too big for a `uint` :)

Comment: _"You could convert the constants to `float64`"_ — this will lose precision.

Comment: @Ruslan that, I presumed, to be self evident.

Comment: *"What I'm interested in is how that code in the standard library doesn't error in the same way?"* -- @ElliotChance because there's no expression in the standard library that would violate the rules laid out in the spec, e.g. there's no `fmt.Println(_S, _W, _B, _M)` in the std lib.