# How do I "manually" set the most significant (32nd) bit of int32 number type?

Tags: go

I'm trying to learn how bits, bytes and memory work and right now I want to directly (manually) set the most significant (32nd) bit of an int32 number to `1` and display the given number. What I expect to get as a result is `-2147483648`. However, I ran into a small problem when trying to implement it.

What I tried is to create two variables, `mask = 1 << 31` (int) and `number = 0` (int32) and to do bitwise OR between them. Unfortunately, there is a type mismatch. The problem is that if I set the mask to be of int32 type, overflow occurs, and if I set the second variable to be of int type, then I will not get the expected result because it is automatically 64 bits and I will not set the most significant bit so my result will be wrong.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    mask := 1 << 31
    var n int32 = 0
    fmt.Println(n | mask)
}
```

I also tried some solutions with unsafe pointers, but I didn't manage to do anything...

I assume that some conversions have to be done, however, I don't know how to do them.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem and set the most significant bit of int32 type numbers?

Comment: Use type conversion: `fmt.Println(n | int32(mask))`

Comment: @icza Thanks, it works, but how... Actually I tried type conversion, but directly when I was setting the value for the mask (`mask := int32(1<<31)`). However, since the biggest number for int32 is `2147483647` and `1<<31` represents int64 `2147483648` value, it did not work and gave me an overflow error. Why does it work in your case, that is, how is that not an overflow?

Comment: See [Does Go compiler's evaluation differ for constant expression and other expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39444852/does-go-compilers-evaluation-differ-for-constant-expression-and-other-expressio/39445372#39445372)

Comment: @icza I did some research and actually came across that answer even before you posted it here. :D Nicely explained! As far as I understand, when defining variables we work with (untyped) constants and then overflow is checked, however, when it comes to variables then overflow is allowed because that behavior is in many languages and it is useful (as in my case). This is exactly why `2147483648` for int64 becomes `-2147483648` for int32 during conversion since the highest bit is 1 and by 2's complement it is negation. Please correct me if I'm wrong. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, that's about it.

Comment: Do bit operations only on unsigned types.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply cast the uint32 to an int32 before you do the mask like so:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    mask := 1 << 31 // is a uint32
    var n int32 = 0
    fmt.Println(n | int32(mask))
}
```

Prints:

```
-2147483648
```

You will find that doing the cast on a literal results in a compile error:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    mask := int32(1 << 31) // is a uint32
    var n int32 = 0
    fmt.Println(n | mask)
}
```

```
./main.go:8:19: cannot convert 1 << 31 (untyped int constant 2147483648) to type int32
```

Comment: `mask := 1 << 31` is not of type **uint32**, but **int**. Whether **int** is 32 or 64 bytes depends on the system (for me its 64).

Answer (score 0):

In Go, the expression `1 << 31` doesn't just mean "a 32-bit value with the most significant bit set". It specifically evaluates to the positive number 2147483648, which doesn't fit into the signed type `int32`.

Your choices are to use `uint32`, which will work but cause the result of your OR to be *positive* 2147483648, or to initialize the mask to the constant -2147483648 instead of using the bit shift.

Answer (score -1):

Use a negative mask value to set the high bit a signed value:

```
const mask int32 = -0x80000000
```

Comment: It would be nice to add some additional explanation here as to why this works.